# How to place variable in char array on arduino?

Tags: arrays, json, arduino, char

these is my code.

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
void setup() {
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
if(Serial.read()=='j')
{
  StaticJsonDocument<256> docc;
  char  json[] =
  "{\"ID\":\"01\",\"Value\":[\"1\",\"2\"]}";
  deserializeJson(docc, json);
  JsonObject object = docc.as<JsonObject>();

  DynamicJsonDocument doc(1024);
 JsonArray result = doc.createNestedArray("result");
  result.add(object);
  serializeJsonPretty(doc,Serial);
  }
}
```

I want to place the variable in json array, like this

```
 "{\"ID\":\"01\",\"Value\":[\"{variable1}\",\{variable2}\"]}";
```

the variable1 and variable2 is char type, i want to read sensor data and assignment, then place these variable to json char array to create json object.
Can anyone give some example to place variable  in the char array?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can either define the json as string like this

```
String json = "{\"ID\":\"01\",\"Value\":[\"{" + variable1 + "}\",\{" + variable2 + "}\"]}";
```

Or you can add to string array like this

```
char *json[] = {
           "{\"ID\":\"01\",\"Value\":[\"{" + variable1 + "}\",\{" + variable2 + "}\"]}"
        };
```

You can check out this Arduino Reference [here](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/)

Also check out the Arduino concatenation reference [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator)

Comment: You can't append multiple c strings in a definition.